# How can I retrieve codings grouped by code categories in the RQDA package in Rstudio?

Tags: rstudio, rqda

Here is an example of the data I am using:

"Q7: How does gender income inequality manifest in the communities in which you live and/or work? What do you believe is needed to help close the wealth gap between men and women as well as among women of different races in the county?
Wouldn’t go into pay equity because that would get dismissed. The wealth gap is a more compelling argument.
Equity is more emotional. And wealth gap is more numbers.  It goes toward the same thing though."

I am running Rstudio and using library(RQDA) and library(tidyverse).

I am trying to analyze several qualitative interviews formatted in question/answer form as in the provided example. I finished the coding process and now I'm trying to find themes. While coding, I created code categories that correspond with each interview question with the hopes that I would be able to pull out all the codings per code category now. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do it and would appreciate some assistance!

thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Questions here are best answered when they are specific, and (ideally) with examples. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but I understood code categories to be helpful for structuring your work by your theoretical perspective. If you create a code category for each interview question (i.e., the topic of the question is your theme/code category), you may have various codes belonging to one "code category", which might not have that much in common. Alternatively, you could create cases (case 1 might be the answers to the first interview question, etc.): "b) Open a file, select part of the file, select a case name, then click button "Link" in "Cases" tab, you can thus link the selected part of file to the selected case" (http://rqda.r-forge.r-project.org/documentation_2.html).